# iphone project resources available in itunes of user

Tags: iphone, mp3

In my iphone project i have a set of 20 mp3 audio files in it.now the whole project is working fine.
    but client has come up with a problem that whenever he installs the app file ,the mp3 files get added to the itunes list..
this should not occur as these should be bought only by inapp purchase...

I had added all mp3 files into the xcode app bundle itself.(by dragging into the resources folder)

Should anything else be done so that mp3 files stay in app itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have 20 .mp3 files in your app bundle, which can be unlocked by inApp purchase? This is far to easy to crack, as one can just look into the bundle and extract the files, as a bundle is basically a folder.

I can't post a complete solution, but consider encrypting the files and set up a web service, which delivers a token to unlock the files after being purchased via inApp purchase.

Comment: well encrypting the resource files would be a great option....but havent done that till now.can u share any tutorials or links that discuss this?

Comment: This blog article shows a very simple to use solution: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html I imagine something like writing a small helper utility which encrypts the files, which you can than put into the app bundle. Than you need to figure a way, how to decrypt the files after inApp purchase. Complex: calling a WebService to get Password including that only your app can call the service. Simple: Store password in code.

Answer (score 0):

Well they should not end up in the MP3 List op iTunes.
Does this happen when the client drags the .app folder into iTunes on windows, if so I could imagine that windows does not recognizes the app and just add the mp3 to his iTunes library.

You could try a service like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) for ad-hoc builds.

Comment: ya it happens when the client drags the .app file into itunes ...but it is in mac itself

Comment: Weird, are you able to reproduce this your self, I've never had any problems. It did add a MP3 as background audio  to one app, but it never showed up in my iTunes library.

Comment: well i couldn't reproduce that....but then customer(client) is God...and i hv no other way but to believe him :)